# Screen Share Disabled Box Appearing Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: vnc

I am currently using screen share and when using vnc to access the machine a disabled icon appears on the screen. It is quite large and overlays the open applications blocking a portion of the screen.

I can only assume this means some input is disabled or something of the sort, but I cannot seem to find any info on it, let alone how to remove it.

All my attempts to find info just tell me how to disable screen sharing or disable a desktop icon.

Can anyone shed some light on what this is and how it can be removed?

The box looks like so:

[image: stupid box]

**Edit**

I am using the screen share option available in ubuntu 18.04 by default.

[Guide to enable this here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-connections-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

I am accessing from a Mac book using VNC viewer.

Comment: What program/platodrm are you using to access the machine? Please edit your question with further information.

Comment: @Graham I have added some extra info, anything else you could think of let me know.

Comment: I use the VNC protocol in Remmina to access a remote PC (Ubunutu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.04) within a discrete LAN and it works perfectly well. What VNC client are you using?